# How to append a prefix to action name according to a particular route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using asp.net mvc 4 and web api. My route is like this:

```
/api/{controller}/jqGrid/{action}/{id}
```

for example, if the route is :

```
/api/User/jqGrid/List
```

I hope it will route to the action name "jqGrid_List" of the User controller.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

hmm, I don't know if it's acceptable to answer my own question. I found out a solution.

First of all, I need to add a JqGridControllerConfiguration attribute to replace the default action selector applied to the controller with my one.

```
[JqGridControllerConfiguration]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    // GET: /api/User/jqGrid/List
    [HttpGet]
    public JqGridModel<User> jqGrid_List()
    {
        JqGridModel<User> result = new JqGridModel<User>();
        result.rows = Get();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here's the code of JqGridControllerConfiguration:

```
public class JqGridControllerConfiguration : Attribute, IControllerConfiguration
{
    public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        controllerSettings.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionSelector), new JqGridActionSelector());
    }
}
```

in JqGridActionSelector, the "action" is modified if a "jqGrid/" exists in the request URL.

```
public class JqGridActionSelector : ApiControllerActionSelector
{
    public override HttpActionDescriptor SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        Uri url = controllerContext.Request.RequestUri;
        if (url.Segments.Any(s => string.Compare(s, "jqGrid/", true) == 0))
        {
            controllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "jqGrid_" + controllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        }

        return base.SelectAction(controllerContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's really an overkill, why don't you use ActionName("List") attribute on the action?

Comment: I want to have two "List" actions in the controller, one for regular calling (/User/List) and one for jqGrid calling (/User/jqGrid/List).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want to do this. But you can still create a "jqGrid_List" action in your User controller and set an ActionName for it, and it'll work.

**UserController**:

```
    [HttpGet, ActionName("List")]
    public string jqGrid_List()
    {
        return "WORKS";
    }
```

Your **Route**:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/jqGrid/{action}/{id}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will have two List actions in the controller, a "/User/List" will call the regular List action and a "/User/jqGrid/List" will call jqGrid_List method. I can make different Url like "/User/jqGrid_List", but I think "/User/jqGrid/List" may be more friendly.

Comment: Name them 2 separate function names. You can give them both the ActionName "List". Then create another route after the route i suggested in my answer above, and remove the 'jqGrid': "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"